# error: The argument type 'File?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'

Tags: flutter, dart

error: The argument type 'File?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [aplikasi_scan_plat_nomor] lib\screen\home.dart:82)

```
File? pickedImage;
image: FileImage(pickedImage),
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dataType is nullable which is OK.

```dart
File? pickedImage;
```

But image doesn't accept null data.
You can do a null check first.

```dart
if(pickedImage!=null)
  YourWidget(
     image: FileImage(pickedImage),
```

Adding null-assert(!) is risky without checking null first.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way would be to do a null check, but you can also assign an initial value your `pickedImage`.

```
File pickedImage = File('initialValue');

image: FileImage(pickedImage),
```